# Demonstrating a Unitary Matrix is Special

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Suppose I have an $n\times n$ *Unitary* matrix $A$, whose elements in the first row and first column are all purely real (with others complex in general)

$$ A=
\begin{pmatrix}
r_{11} & r_{12} & r_{13} & \\
r_{21} & c_{22} & c_{23} & \ldots\\
r_{31} & c_{32} & c_{33} & \\
&\vdots&&\ddots
\end{pmatrix}\qquad
r_{ij}\in \mathbb{R}, \enspace c_{ij}\in \mathbb{C}\,.
$$

Is it possible to show, for specific sizes $n$, that $A$ is in fact *special unitary*?  That is, $\det(A) = 1$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$ A=
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 & i\\
\end{pmatrix}
$$

$$det(A) = i$$